# Cropping like iPhoto in iOS 4.X for iPad

Tags: xcode, image, ipad, ios4, crop

I want to write an iOS App with an graphical interface for image cropping.

The user should able to make with multitouch gestures a cropping rect over an imageview like apples iphoto cropping function.

how could i realize that?
are there any prepared classes on the web?

regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but would help.

[SSPhotoCropperViewController is a custom view controller that provides UI for cropping and scaling photos in iPhone / iPod Touch apps.](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController)